# Apache Bad Request (400) and time shift in logfile

Tags: apache-2.4, django, 400

My web server utilizes Apache and Django for its web service. Occasionally, the web service produces a "Bad Request (400)" error. After reviewing the error log, I noticed that there is a 6-hour time difference in the system time and  time in the log (attached image).
[image]

Could someone provide insight into the potential cause of this issue and how to resolve it?

EDIT1: Output of command `sudo journalctl --utc` suggested by @J.M.Robles

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: It seems that logs for different apache modules have different timezones. If the timezone for the server has changed after the last restart of apache, perhaps a restart now could fix the issue. Have you restarted apache recently?

Comment: @J.M.Robles. Yes we did restart Apache multiple times. However, it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: To confirm (or not) whether these are lines with dates in different time zones, I suggest using journalctl with the --utc option or with the --output=short-full option

Comment: I have included a new figure in the main query.  I do not see timezone related information in the output of `journalctl` .

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of the issue (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/). It is written in the warning. I have resolved it.